# Interest query for dates less total payment date

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following table "detallepre".

```
 Cuota  DateCuota  DatePaid   Capital  Interest  Status 
------  ----------  ----------  -------  -------  --------
     1  2018-05-07  2018-05-07  722.62   265.78         -1
     2  2018-06-06  2018-06-06  741.67   246.73         -1
     3  2018-07-06  2018-07-07  768.64   219.76         -1
     4  2018-08-05  2018-07-07  2305.92  400.00         -1
     5  2018-09-04  2018-07-07  5543.42  646.63         -1
```

Where Quota Date is the scheduled date to pay and Paid Date is the date that the payment was made, according to the table the 1 and 2 installment was paid on the scheduled date and the 3,4 and 5 installment was paid on the same day 2018-07 -07, was the total payment of interest, the State is -1 for Paid and 1 for Debt. I want to obtain the sum of interest until the end of the month that I indicate, with an exception that I will explain at the end. For example, if I consult until June, I use the following query.

```
SELECT IFNULL (SUM (Interest), 0) Interest FROM detailpre WHERE DateQuota <= '2018-06-30'
```

result: **512.51** correct

Consult until July:

```
SELECT IFNULL (SUM (Interest), 0) Interest FROM detailpre WHERE DateQuota <= '2018-07-30'
```

result: **732.27** correct

Consult until August, this is where I have a problem.

```
SELECT IFNULL (SUM (Interest), 0) Interest FROM detailpre WHERE DateQuota <= '2018-08-30'
```

result: **1132.27** Incorrect (I say incorrect because it is not the expected result)

What I hope to get is 732.27 since the total payment date (when all the remaining installments were paid) was in July 2018-07-07, and should not continue adding the interest since the fees are paid, as it should be my query if I do it within a stored procedure, where it would indicate the Date parameter, as far as I would like it to do the calculation, sorry for my bad English, Thank you

**UPDATE**

I will try to explain better, what I want is to obtain the total interest until the date that I indicate (which is usually the end of the month), in the case that I consult until the month of August, September, etc onwards, I hope to obtain 732.27 as in July , since the quota 4 and 5, corresponding to August and September were already paid in July, therefore they would not add those interests and there would only be 732.27,
maybe the sql query that I put is not the correct one for this case, I use MySQL Version: 5.6.34
Thank you

Comment: I'm missing how 'all remaining instalments where paid'. Is the interest and interest paid or accrued? Don't apologize for your English, its perfectly understandable :-) Edit question to include this and please add your MySQL version. You don't need to use a stored procedure, they can make things harder.

Comment: @danblack edit my question, thx